# AWS Lambda SequelizeDatabaseError: Connection lost: The server closed the connection

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sequelize.js, aws-step-functions

I am using a lambda in a state machine that is repetitively called after 2-hour,24-hour,48-hour interval.Problem is that first execution works but second fails with the error SequelizeDatabaseError: Connection lost: The server closed the connection. Screenshots for state machine and Error logs are below:
[image: state machine and error shown]

Comment: What do you have inside your Lambda? Any sql connection?

Comment: Yes there is a SQL connection @PooyaParidel

Comment: So my guess was right, the issue is related to DB connection and how you are doing it inside Lambda. Seems like the cold start works and any repeatitive call to Lambda causing an issue.